# variables single quoted in function call, why?

Tags: function, arguments, sh

I have this problem, I have two (bourne) shell scripts, ony with subroutines, the other with the main program.

The problem lies in the argument-passing.

In my subroutine script I have this:

`test()
{
 echo "$1"
}`

When called from the main program like this:

`test "foo bar"`

The result of the echo is 'foo bar' (note the single quotes)
When I modify my test to this:

`test()
{
 FOOBAR="foo bar";
 echo "$FOOBAR"
}`

Then the result does not contain quotes.

Then subroutinescript is sourced like this:

`. testroutines.sh`

Using sh -x I see the variable that is passed *seems* to be quoted with single quotes?

What am I missing?

Comment: I only want to accept an answer if it is acceptable one. Maybe my questions are hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have to do with the IFS, it was incorrectly set. It didn't contain a space.